# How to draw a grid in a bar-plot created with plt.vlines()

Tags: matplotlib

I want to create a bar-plot in python. I want this plot to be beautiful though and I don't like the looks of python's `axes.bar()` function. Therefore, I have decided to use `plt.vlines()`. The challenge here is that my x-data is a list that contains strings and not numerical data. When I plot my graph, the spacing between the two columns (in my example column 2 = 0) is pretty big:

[image]

Furthermore, I want a grid. However, I would like to have minor grid lines as well. I know how to get all of this if my data was numerical. But since my x-data contains strings, I don't know how to set x_max. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, the positions of the labels are numbered 0,1,... So setting the x-limits a bit before 0 and after the last, shows them more centered.

Usually, bars are drawn with their 'feet' on the ground, which can be set via `plt.ylim(0, ...)`. Minor ticks can be positioned for example at multiples of 0.2.  Setting the length of the ticks to zero lets the position count for the grid, but suppresses the tick mark.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import numpy as np

labels = ['Test 1', 'Test 2']
values = [1, 0.7]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.vlines(labels, 0, values, colors='dodgerblue', alpha=.4, lw=7)

plt.xlim(-0.5, len(labels) - 0.5)  # add some padding left and right of the bars
plt.ylim(0, 1.1)  # bars usually have their 0 at the bottom

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(.2))
plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', length=0) # ticks not shown, but position serves for gridlines
plt.grid(axis='both', which='both', ls=':') # optionally set the linestyle of the grid

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: thx a lot JohanC! One question: When you set the length of the ticks to 0, why can I still see the labels (Test 1, Test 2) ? I definitely want to see them, but I am a bit confused

Comment: The 'ticks' are just the short lines, so making them shorter only moves the labels nearer to the axes.